# Get attribute value of textbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having hard time to get attribute value of one textbox.

This is what I have in Firebug:

[image]

I tried different approaches, such as prop(), attr(), val() but without any success.

Any idea how can I get that value?

Comment: what does your HTML look like?

Comment: attr should do it if it's indeed a html attribute

Comment: Have you tried `.val()`?

Comment: I tried val() as well

Comment: @BrianGlaz html screenshot http://i.gyazo.com/00953876996dafef5a4b3acde252c12f.png

Comment: $("#QUEST7_prefix").val();

Comment: Do you have unique names for each of your elements? Using `.val()` should work if your selector is correct. Usually, it's good to post a code fragment that can reproduce the problem instead of screenshots of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `id` of the `input` with `val()` like this:

```
$('#QUEST7_prefix').val();
```

Or, if you insist on using the `name` attribute, you should do this:

```
$('input[name=QUEST7_prefix]').val();
```

Both return the same result.

Here is a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/balabo/1/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: I'm getting undefined

Comment: Have you entered anything in the `input`?

Comment: 2nd option helped me, thx, I'll accept your answer as soon as I can, have a good day

Answer (score 1):

`var name = $("input[name='QUEST7_prefix']").attr("name")`

or in plain javascript

`var el = document.getElementById("someEl")[0]`

`var name = el.getAttribute("name")`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are executing code before the html gets rendered. Try this:

```
$(function(){
    alert($('#QUEST7_prefix').val());
});
```